# What is the Probability Density Function of the Binomial Distribution?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, random-variables, binomial-distribution

Suppose we have the Probability Mass Function (PMF) of the Binomial Distribution here:

$Bin(k|n,\theta) = {n \choose k} \theta^k (1 - \theta)^{n-k}$

How do we derive the Probability Density Function (PDF)?
Is that not possible since 'k' in this case is a discrete random variable and not continuous?

Comment: Discrete random variables do not have a density.  They do have a cumulative distribution function

Comment: It is common to interpret the PDF as a density w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure. In that context a discrete random variable has no PDF (as @Henry remarks). Nevertheless in the discrete situation the PMF is actually also a density, but this w.r.t. a suitable counting measure.